# Submit Form Without Reloading Page and Get Output [PHP, jQuery]

Tags: php, jquery

Hellow,
I've been trying to submit a form without reloading and getting PHP output on the same page. The main objective is to submit the form values to a PHP file and get the output sent by the PHP file.
To understand it better, let's take a look on following code snippet:
HTML & jQuery Code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {

        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'on.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('form was submitted');
            }
          });

        });

      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input id="name" name="name"><br>
      <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name=$_POST['name'];
if($name == 'Johny'){
    echo "Welcome Johny";
}
else{
echo "I Dont Know You";
}
}
?>
```

What I Want:

- When user enter value in the Input box and submit it, the page should display output value e.g ECHO value without reloading the webpage.

Comment: How about using json_encode in your PHP file and then getting that value in the success callback of your function?

Comment: Can you explain it by using json_encode in the code given above!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be more specific on my first comment, you have to put an exit statement after you echo the response so the rest of the code doesn't execute, also to check whether the form was sent or not you can add a hidden input in your form with the value "1" (`<input name="formSent" type="hidden" value="1">`) that gets checked in your PHP :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['formSent'])){
$name=$_POST['name'];
if($name == 'Johny'){
  echo "Welcome Johny";
  exit;
}
else{
  echo "I Dont Know You";
  exit;
}
}
?>
```

and then get the response from the ajax request in the success's callback parameter, also specify the `method: 'POST'` because jQuery's $.ajax function uses the method **GET** by default:

```
<script>
  $(function () {

    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'on.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function (message) {
          alert(message);
        }
      });

    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: are you sure you change "echo" with "return"? Because the ajax request from the page you gave is sending the whole html page as a response.

Comment: Oh now I get it, the PHP is on the same page, then you'd have to put the PHP code at the top of your page, before the HTML content.

Comment: The reason why your code isn't working is because you haven't defined a method in your form. Your looking for set POST data but by default forms use the GET method.

Comment: PHP is on the top of page, here's the sequence: PHP>JQUERY>FORM

Comment: why you use dataType: 'json' in ajax request.

Comment: @Enoch : this, I forgot that one, by default the $.ajax sends a GET request, to change that, put : method: 'POST' in the ajax function

Comment: I've set form method to POST and it's not working :/

Comment: I just updated my answer, sorry for misleading you, you were right about the "echo" of the result but just have to add an "exit;" so the rest of the code would not be executed and also change the if statement to "if (isset($_POST['name']))"

Comment: Works perfectly, Thanks for your efforts and time :)

Comment: You're welcome, usually I use JSON responses but I know it can be overwhelming if you never heard of it before.

Comment: i know about it but haven't worked before on AJAX for and stuff like i'm doing right now. It's always overwhelming for me when someone put his time and efforts in solving my problems :)

Comment: Hey, in PHP code, we've used if (isset($_POST['name'])), it checks is name is submitted or not, but what it i want to check that entire form is submitted or not!

Comment: @Paul : then you would have to add an additional hidden input that you can check on the PHP side (checking the submit input doesn't work for some reason), I've updated the code